# Error in fetching deselected date in flatpickr

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I am using `flatpickr` as a datetime picker on my app. This date picker allows for multiple dates to be selected. I am getting the date which I have last selected (the dates which are selected looks like marked ). But the problem is when I choose a date randomly from multiple dates I can't fetch that date .

Here is my jQuery Code

```
$("#available-calendar").flatpickr({
    disableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    inline: true,
    mode: "multiple",
    minDate: "today",

    defaultDate: newDates,
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        var selectedDates = dateStr.split(",");
        var latestDate = selectedDates[selectedDates.length-1];
        console.log(latestDate);
        alert(latestDate);
    },
});
```

here `newDates` are array Of Dates fetching from database.

Comment: I still get latest date. Check my demo
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaEGOK

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the problem is I need the date which I deselect.  But I am getting the previous date which was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid there is no support method from `flatpickr` now. I will give you a trick to get deselected date by store it in `global variable`. it might work in your case

```
$(() => {
  let defaultDate = ["2018-06-20", "2018-06-22"]
  let selected = _.cloneDeep(defaultDate)
  $("#test").flatpickr({
    disableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    inline: true,
    mode: "multiple",
    minDate: "today",
    defaultDate: defaultDate,
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {

      let newDate = _.chain(dateStr)
        .split(',')
        .map(_.trim)
        .value();
      if (newDate.length < selected.length ) {
        let deselected = _.difference(selected, newDate);
        console.log(deselected)
      } 
      selected = _.cloneDeep(newDate)
    }
  });
});
```

demo => https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaEGOK

Comment: There is a slight problem, when I deselect the date it returns null value, again when I deselect 2nd time(other selected date) it is working i.e returning the deselected value.